# WHEREIS Command not returning result in AIX

Tags: unix, aix

Environment: AIX 5

Using *whereis* does not return the file-names of source/binary files I am looking for.

For example:

> whereis FILE

returns

> whereis:

Also tried the above command with suitable command options (-b , -m, -s) .. still the same result.

Anyone aware of the change required to modify the syntax of this command to suit the AIX Unix flavor.

Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: there is a `which <program>` on AIX

Answer (score 0):

I wish folks who ask questions about AIX would put the version of AIX they are running.

whereis works on my 6.1 machine and my 5.3 machine.  I usually use `type`.  It is in ksh and in bash and it is built-in.  Here is a log of some commands I did:

```
type whereis
whereis is /bin/whereis

whereis whereis
whereis: /usr/bin/whereis
```

What fileset is where is in?

```
lslpp -w /usr/bin/whereis
  File                                        Fileset               Type
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /usr/bin/whereis                            bos.rte.commands      File
```

Ok.  what level of that fileset do I have?

```
lslpp -ch bos.rte.commands
#Path:Fileset:Level:PTF Id:Action:Status:Date:Time
/usr/lib/objrepos:bos.rte.commands:6.1.8.16::APPLY:COMPLETE:12/26/13:14;44;04
/etc/objrepos:bos.rte.commands:6.1.8.16::APPLY:COMPLETE:12/26/13:14;44;08
```

I thought whereis use to be a script but on my hosts they are binary executables.  Here is the output of `what` on my 5.3 host:

```
what /usr/bin/whereis
/usr/bin/whereis:
        61      1.14  src/bos/usr/ccs/lib/libc/__threads_init.c, libcthrd, bos530 7/11/00 12:04:14
        93      1.13  src/bos/usr/bin/whereis/whereis.c, cmdscan, bos53H, h2005_32B1 7/6/05 08:53:01
```

And from my 6.1 host:

```
what /usr/bin/whereis
/usr/bin/whereis:
        61      1.16  src/bos/usr/ccs/lib/libc/__threads_init.c, libcthrd, bos61B, b2007_33A0 8/2/07 13:09:21
        93      1.13.1.1  src/bos/usr/bin/whereis/whereis.c, cmdscan, bos610 2/11/07 14:12:18
```

I would not be surprised if the `SHELL` environment variable is involved in all this so you might see if it is set to something odd.  I keep my `SHELL` set to `/usr/bin/ksh` and then I have my `.kshrc` exec's me over to `bash`.  Some scripts on AIX do not have the `#!/usr/bin/ksh` at the top which causes some issues.  At this date, I have not bumped into that in a while.

I'm curious what you find.  I'm curious what level of AIX you are running.

Good luck